# Switched from create-react-app to webpack. And now routes won't load if they are accessed using the address bar

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I used to have create-react-app , and my app worked fine.
But I had to switch to webpack in order to manage some issues like ports.

Point is, I switched, the app works fine now. But... im having an issue, and its that my routes stopped working when accessed using the navigation/Address bar of the browser. I can still navigate throught them using history.push and clicking on the buttons that trigger those actions. But whenever I type something in the address bar it crashes with the error.

```
Cannot GET /admin
```

And not only /admin crashes, all my different routes, except the main one "/" crash, with the same error. Cannot GET ...

This is how my webpack.config.js looks

```
    var path = require('path')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {fs: 'empty'},
    plugins : [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin ({
            template : 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

This is how I launch the app with `npm run start`

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --port 3004 --open",
"build": "webpack --mode production"
```

},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add this to the config file

```
    devServer: {
  hot: true,
  contentBase: './',
  historyApiFallback: true
},
```

And it solved the issue